# Scala SBT Plugin Version Error During Build

Tags: scala, sbt, github-actions, scoverage

I keep getting the following error from my GitHub Actions workflow:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.7.1 (Eclipse Adoptium Java 11.0.16.1)
[info] loading settings for project plant-simulator-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /home/runner/work/plant-simulator/plant-simulator/project
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      org.scoverage:sbt-scoverage:2.0.7 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scoverage:sbt-scoverage;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:2.0.7
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scoverage/sbt-scoverage_2.12_1.0/2.0.7/sbt-scoverage-2.0.7.pom
[error]   not found: /home/runner/.ivy2/localorg.scoverage/sbt-scoverage/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.0.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scoverage/sbt-scoverage/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.0.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scoverage/sbt-scoverage/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.0.7/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:345)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$38(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:314)
[error]     at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:314)
```

I have the following defined in my project/plugins.sbt file:

```
// For code coverage test
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "2.0.7")
```

My question is, why is it taking the 2.12_1.0 scoverage version instead of 2.12.17_2.0.7? This is ruining my build. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, why is it taking the 2.12_1.0 scoverage version instead of 2.12.17_2.0.7?

It's not. It is trying to find version 2.0.7 of the plugin. The 2.12 refer to the Scala version of plugins expected by SBT (different from the version of your project), and 1.0 refer to SBT major version.

The error message is relatively clear:

```
Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
      org.scoverage:sbt-scoverage:2.0.7 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
```

> This is ruining my build. Any ideas on how to fix this?

There's no version 2.0.7 as of today. Latest is 2.0.5. Check out the GitHub page of the plugin for reference: https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage.

Comment: You may be correct, I tried with 2.0.6 and I'm now hitting another error that I need to fix.